# Making animation more efficient

Tags: performance-tuning, animation

I created some code to create a nice animation. However, it takes a considerable amount of time to run it. I would like to make it run in the least amount of time possible.

First, I load two packages I need: [LevelScheme](https://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) and [MaTeX](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/9355/).
Once I install them I use

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
AppendTo[$Path, "/mypath/LevelScheme"];
Get["LevelScheme`"]
SetOptions[LinTicks, MajorTickLength -> {0.02, 0}, MinorTickLength -> {0.013, 0}];
```

Next, I am going create two new long functions

```
\[Psi]TimeDep[x_, r_, \[Phi]_, \[Alpha]_, t_] := 
 1/Sqrt[Cosh[r]]*((m \[Omega])/(\[Pi] h))^(1/4) *
  Exp[-((m \[Omega])/(2 h))*x^2 - 
    Conjugate[\[Alpha]]/
     2 (\[Alpha] + Conjugate[\[Alpha]] E^(I \[Phi])*Tanh[r]) - (
    I*\[Omega]*t)/
    2 - (m \[Omega])/h E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t)*
     x^2 + (\[Alpha] + Conjugate[\[Alpha]] E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r])*
     E^(-I*\[Omega]*t)*Sqrt[(2 m \[Omega])/h] x - 
    1/2*(E^(-I*\[Omega]*
         t)*(\[Alpha] + Conjugate[\[Alpha]] E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]) - 
       E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t)*Sqrt[(2 m \[Omega])/h] E^(I \[Phi])
         Tanh[r] x)^2 - 
    Log[1 - E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t)]/
    2 - ((E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t))/(
      1 - E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t))) *1/
     2*(E^(-I*\[Omega]*
         t)*(\[Alpha] + Conjugate[\[Alpha]] E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]) - 
       E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t)*Sqrt[(2 m \[Omega])/h] E^(I \[Phi])
         Tanh[r] x)^2]

\[CapitalPhi]TimeDep[p_, r_, \[Phi]_, \[Alpha]_, t_] := 
 1/Sqrt[Cosh[r]]*(1/(\[Pi] h m \[Omega]))^(1/4) *
  Exp[-(1/(2 h m \[Omega]))*p^2 - 
    Conjugate[\[Alpha]]/
     2 (\[Alpha] + Conjugate[\[Alpha]] E^(I \[Phi])*Tanh[r]) - (
    I*\[Omega]*t)/2 + 
    1/(h m \[Omega]) E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t) *p^2 - 
    I (\[Alpha] + Conjugate[\[Alpha]] E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r])*
     E^(-I*\[Omega]*t)*Sqrt[2 /(m \[Omega] h)] p + 
    1/2*(E^(-I*\[Omega]*
         t)*(\[Alpha] + Conjugate[\[Alpha]] E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]) + 
       I*Sqrt[2/(m \[Omega] h)] E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]*
        E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t)* p)^2 - 
    1/2 Log[1 + 
       E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]*
        E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t)] - ((E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]*
         E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t))/(1 + 
         E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]*E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t))) *1/
     2*(E^(-I*\[Omega]*
         t)*(\[Alpha] + Conjugate[\[Alpha]] E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]) + 
       I Sqrt[2/(h m \[Omega])] E^(I \[Phi]) Tanh[r]*
        E^(-2*I*\[Omega]*t)* p)^2]
```

where `m=1;h=1;\[Omega]=1`.
Then, I create four new simple functions

```
deltaX[r_, t_] := 
 Sqrt[h/(2*m*\[Omega])] Sqrt[Cosh[2*r] - Sinh[2*r]*Cos[2*\[Omega]*t]]

deltaP[r_, t_] := 
 Sqrt[(h*m*\[Omega])/2] Sqrt[Cosh[2*r] + Sinh[2*r]*Cos[2*\[Omega]*t]]

expectedX[\[Alpha]_, t_] := 
 Sqrt[h/(2*
   m*\[Omega])] (E^(-I*\[Omega]*t)*\[Alpha] + 
    E^(I*\[Omega]*t)*Conjugate[\[Alpha]])

expectedP[\[Alpha]_, t_] := 
 I*Sqrt[(h*m*\[Omega])/
  2] (-E^(-I*\[Omega]*t)*\[Alpha] + 
    E^(I*\[Omega]*t)*Conjugate[\[Alpha]])
```

Now it is time to create a table of the plots that I will eventually animate.  NOTE: I used `alpha=3(1+I)` and `r=2`

```
p1[r_, alpha_, t_] := 
  Plot[Re[\[Psi]TimeDep[x, r, 0, alpha, t]], {x, -40, 40}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-0.4, 0.4}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0042], Blue}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   FrameTicks -> LinTicks, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 20], 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
   Prolog -> {Opacity[0.5, Gray], 
     Rectangle[{N[Re[expectedX[alpha, t]]] - N[deltaX[r, t]]/
        2, -0.4}, {N[Re[expectedX[alpha, t]]] + N[deltaX[r, t]]/2, 
       0.4}]}, Epilog -> {Text[Style["(a)", Black, Italic, 20], 
      Scaled[{.9, .9}]], 
     Text[Style["Position space", Blue, 20], Scaled[{.19, .1}]]}, 
   Axes -> {True, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, 
     MaTeX["\\text{Re }{\\psi}_{\\xi,\\alpha}(x,t)", FontSize -> 23]},
    ImagePadding -> {{80, 45}, {0, 30}}, ImageSize -> 600];

p2[r_, alpha_, t_] := 
  Plot[Re[\[CapitalPhi]TimeDep[x, r, 0, alpha, t]], {x, -40, 40}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-0.4, 0.4}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0042], Red}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   FrameTicks -> LinTicks, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, FontSize -> 20], 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
   Prolog -> {Opacity[0.5, Gray], 
     Rectangle[{N[Re[expectedP[alpha, t]]] - (1)*N[deltaP[r, t]]/
         2, -0.4}, {N[Re[expectedP[alpha, t]]] + (1)*N[deltaP[r, t]]/
         2, 0.4}]}, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["(b)", Black, Italic, 20], Scaled[{.9, .9}]],
      Text[Style["Momentum space", Red, 20], Scaled[{.19, .1}]]}, 
   Axes -> {True, False}, 
   FrameLabel -> {MaTeX["\\text{Coordinates }x\\text{ and } p", 
      FontSize -> 23], 
     MaTeX["\\text{Re }\\tilde{\\psi}_{\\xi,\\alpha}(p,t)", 
      FontSize -> 23]}, ImagePadding -> {{80, 45}, {60, 0}}, 
   ImageSize -> 600];
```

Finally, I make the animation and export it as a .gif file

```
animation = 
  Table[Column[{p1[2,3*(1+I),t], p2[2,3*(1+I),t]}, Spacings -> 0], {t, 0, 12.68, 0.08}];

Export["/mypath/animationX.gif", animation, 
 "AnimationRepetitions" -> \[Infinity]]
```

Could someone suggest me a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Do you just want to get results faster? Have you tried `ParallelTable` to generate your `animation`? Otherwise, have you benchmarked your functions to see which one is the bottleneck? That's what I would do first if this was my problem. But since it's not my problem, I'll let *you* do it :-) Let us know what you find then edit the question with that info.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes. All I want is get results faster. I replaced `Table` by `ParallelTable` and that worked pretty well.